# Can I make up puzzles for the site?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to Puzzling and figured I would get started by posting a puzzle.

I read through the tour, and it says this:

> Ask about...
>
> Specific questions about the creation and solving of puzzles
>
> Real problems or questions that you have encountered

Am I allowed to make up my own puzzles for the site?

Meta doesn't have an answer, and the [on-topic page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't have anything in it.

A lot of puzzles look like they were made up, but I can't tell.

Comment: Every puzzle I've posted so far has been made up by me - feel free to ask your own madeup puzzles!

Comment: Not only can you, but there's a special sandbox for getting feedback on it before you post it! It's like a special QA environment for puzzles :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you look through the recent posts on this site, probably upward of 90% are user-created puzzles, so ***go for it***!

You might want to read a bit about what makes a good/bad puzzle, though:

- [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717)
- [What are the features of a well-written puzzle?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5880)
- [How do I write a "solid" Riddle?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5249)
- [How do you come up with a good classic rhyme riddle?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105)
- [What should you look for when rating the difficulty of a puzzle?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5885)
- [How specific should a puzzle be?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413)
- [Finding the fine line between too-easy and too-hard puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3185)
- [The many-eyes effect](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2947)
- [Are math-textbook-style problems on topic?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783)
- [How can I form good hints for (sequence) puzzles?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4683)

You may also want to look at past gems for inspiration:

- [Best puzzles of 2014?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1759)
- [Best puzzles of 2015 Q1?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2910)
- [Best puzzles of 2015 Q2?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3183)
- [Best puzzles of 2015 Q3 (July - September)?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4382)
- [Best puzzles of 2015 Q4 (October - December)?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4466)
- [Puzzle Of The Year 2015!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4488)
- [Best puzzles of 2016 Q1 (January - March)?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4631)
- [Best puzzles of 2016 Q2 (April - June)?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5051)

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for asking! The Puzzling site has had some different 'starting' and then grew into it's current, rather special state. It is - like CodeGolf - a somewhat untypical StackExchange site and as result not all of the auxiliary pages (FAQ etc.) are fully representative.
There has also been a (turbulent) time of discussion and very different opinions of what this site is about, but in the end, this site became what it is: The *perfect* site to post your own puzzles to showcase them, test them against possibly the best puzzle-solving-community in the world, and to learn how to make *good* puzzles. Focus is on *quality* not quantity, though.