# Best puzzles of 2016 Q1 (January - March)?

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).*

---

> ### *What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the first quarter (Jan/ Feb / Mar) 2016?*

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it), instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

> Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):
>
> - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2016 Q1](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579?StartDate=2016/01/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2016 Q1](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705?StartDate=2016/01/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2016 Q1](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709?StartDate=2016/01/01#query-results)

---

Meta-meta issues:

- Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?

  - Yes, [photo.SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [scifi.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3142/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-third-quarter-of-2013?rq=1) do something very similar.
- What's the point?

  - To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.
  - To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'. :)
  - To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.

Comment: So, to clarify, are we voting on posts from the First Quarter of 2016 or on posts from the Fourth Quarter of 2015 as the 2016Q1 vote?  I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I think that was a typo.  We are voting on posts that were made between January 1 and March 31, 2016.

Comment: Okay - thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 29):

### [This is important. I need you to listen…](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28494/this-is-important-i-need-you-to-listen)

*by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)*

A wonderful construction that mixes visual elements with crossword clues, Vignere keys, ambigrams, and many other ideas. The puzzle is multi-layered and extremely difficult, but still the solution is clear and well-motivated. Furthermore, @Deusovi's solution to this puzzle should be a worthy nominee for the best-solution award of 2016/Q1.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed a wonderful puzzle. Getting my vote this turn.

Comment: Wow! That is impressive. Thanks for nominating it here - I would have missed it otherwise.

Comment: @AE I think this is the true purpose of the *best of* series - creating a collection of "not to be missed" puzzles from that time-period.

Answer (score 5):

## [Batman and the piano](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29278)

*by [Khale_Kitha](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19944)*

A well-designed multi-layered puzzle with a pleasant visual aspect that requires a lot of work, but is rewarding.

The setup and in-character response of the puzzle creator add to the enjoyment.

Answer (score 5):

### [You've Probably Seen Me Naked](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28201/youve-probably-seen-me-naked)

*by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain)*

Very well written. Every sentence had different answers and no other answer could be as beautiful as the intended answers. It was enjoyable even to see the puzzle getting solved.

Answer (score 4):

### [Jump to the 13th dimension](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29338/jump-to-the-13th-dimension)

*by [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest)*

Detailed and well put together (almost) purely visual puzzle. Initially seems impenetrable, but has enough subtle clues amongst the red herrings to draw you towards the appropriate threads to pull at, allowing you to unravel (pun intended) the solution.

Answer (score 3):

### [The Three Little Pigs are hiding something](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25214)

by *[Volatility](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/8949)*

An extremely clever and meticulously-constructed puzzle with layers of decryption required, but sufficiently clued to solve it easily (once the decryption methods have been figured out).  Even the title is actually a hint to the solution, as well as the encryption method.